# Debugging MS Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBScript Macro being run from MS Excel 2007. 5 minutes ago, when I debugged, if the code made changes to the excel doc that was open, I could see those changes in real time as I stepped through the code. All of a sudden, I don't see most of the changes in the Excel file.

Comment: VBScript or VBA? Care to show us the code so we have some sort of a chance?

Comment: It's VBScript, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Why not 100% sure? Care to show us?

Comment: When the excel file stops being updated do ctrl+break to enter debug mode.  Inspect.  Especially screen updating.

Answer (score 4):

Have you perhaps set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False`?

Comment: I have not set Application.ScreenUpdating to anything, and all of a sudden the excel file is updating again. Not sure why.It's VBScript, I'm pretty sure.